# Windows 8 app print preview doesn't always render

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to setup printing for my Windows 8 app, but for some reason the pages do not always render in the preview. Sometimes they are just delayed, sometimes they only render some of the pages, and other occasionally it will just time out and saay "No preview." I have reduced the code to the simplest example that still exhibits the behavior which is basically just a red box on each page.

**PrintingTest.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBox Name="WebAddress" Text="http://slashdot.org" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,40,10,10" Width="400"/>
            <Button Content="Go" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10,40,10,10"/>
            <Button Content="Print" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="10,40,10,10"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <WebView x:Name="PrintingWebView" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="800" Opacity="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        <WebView Name="TheWebView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  LoadCompleted="TheWebView_LoadCompleted"/>

        <StackPanel x:Name="PrintingRoot" Grid.Row="1">
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Width="100" Height="100"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

**PrintingTest.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.TheWebView.Source = new Uri(this.WebAddress.Text);

            PrintController.PrintingWebView = this.PrintingWebView;
            PrintController.PrintingPanel = this.PrintingRoot;
            PrintController.DocumentTitle = this.WebAddress.Text;

            PrintController.RegisterForPrinting();
        }

        // Go
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.TheWebView.Source = new Uri(this.WebAddress.Text);
        }

        // Print
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
        }


    }
```

**PrintController.cs**

```
public static void RegisterForPrinting()
        {
            //await Windows.Graphics.Printing.PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();

            // Create the PrintDocument.
            printDocument = new PrintDocument();

            // Save the DocumentSource.
            printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;

            // Add an event handler which creates preview pages.
            printDocument.Paginate += Paginate;

            // Add an event handler which provides a specified preview page.
            printDocument.GetPreviewPage += GetPrintPreviewPage;

            // Add an event handler which provides all final print pages.
            printDocument.AddPages += AddPrintPages;

            // Create a PrintManager and add a handler for printing initialization.
            PrintManager printMan = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
            printMan.PrintTaskRequested += PrintTaskRequested;
        }


        private static void PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintTask printTask = null;
            printTask = e.Request.CreatePrintTask(DocumentTitle, sourceRequested =>
            {
                printTask.Options.DisplayedOptions.Clear();

                // Print Task event handler is invoked when the print job is completed.
                printTask.Completed += async (s, args) =>
                {
                    // Notify the user when the print operation fails.
                    if (args.Completion == PrintTaskCompletion.Failed)
                    {

                    }

                };

                sourceRequested.SetSource(printDocumentSource);
            });
        }

        private static void AddPrintPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;

            PrintingPanel.Children.Clear();

            // Loop over all of the preview pages and add each one to  add each page to be printed
            for (int i = 0; i < pages.Count(); i++)
            {
                UIElement grid = pages[i];

                printDoc.AddPage(grid);
            }

            // Indicate that all of the print pages have been provided
            printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
        }

        private static void Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
        {
            pages = new List<UIElement>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

                Grid grid = new Grid();
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle() { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
                rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                grid.Children.Add(rectangle);

                PrintingPanel.Children.Add(grid);
                PrintingPanel.InvalidateMeasure();
                PrintingPanel.UpdateLayout();

                pages.Add(grid);
            }
            PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;

            // Report the number of preview pages created
            printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(5, PreviewPageCountType.Intermediate);
        }

        private static void GetPrintPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument printDoc = (PrintDocument)sender;

            printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, pages[e.PageNumber - 1]);

        }
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I found that the `GetPreviewPage` event gets called twice...

Comment: I did not find the underlying cause, but I did find a workaround. SetPreviewPage can be called as many times as you need for the same page. So, I created a 0 millisecond timer. When the timer elapses SetPreviewPage is called again to update the page.

Comment: PrintController.PrintingWebView = this.PrintingWebView;
            PrintController.PrintingPanel = this.PrintingRoot;
            PrintController.DocumentTitle = this.WebAddress.Text;                              How are the above functions declared in printcontroller class. Can you please give me the code.

Comment: Hi may I know How to bind Webview data to printcontroller class ?